# unable to get user's input in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Please find my index.js file .  i want to get user's input . In the "Default welcome Intent" i am unable getting the user's input using "input". when i am using actionsdk, i am able to get user's input through "input". but in dialogflow i am unable to get it. It is showing in the google assessment as "Welcome to my dialogFlow agent! [object Object]."

For the "Test Intent" i have created a entity @sys.ordinal, with parameter name "ordinal",  i din't get any values. Please let me know, how to solve the issue.
     Please share the guide, to find the methods and global varibles available in the object request,response and conv

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as gApp from 'actions-on-google';
import { myService } from './services/myService';
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
const app = gApp.dialogflow({debug: true});

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; 

//exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
//{


  app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv,input) => {
    conv.ask(`Welcome to my dialogFlow agent! <say-as >${input}</say-as>.</speak>`);
    conv.data.question = 'question1';

  });


app.intent('Test Intent',(conv,params) => {
    let qNo:string  =   conv.data.question;
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application'
    +`<say-as >`+conv.params.ordinal+`</say-as>.</speak>`);
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application'+`<say-as >`+qNo+`</say-as>.</speak>`);
    });

  exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest(app);
//});
```

Comment: i got from "conv.input.raw"

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the parameter name to extract out. In your case, it's `ordinal`.

```es6
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv, { original }) => {
  conv.ask(`Welcome to my dialogFlow agent! <say-as >${original}</say-as>.</speak>`);
  conv.data.question = 'question1';
});
```

The second argument for a Dialogflow Intent Handler is a object that's a map of parameter names to parameter values.

You could also use it like an object instead.

```es6
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv, params) => {
  conv.ask(`Welcome to my dialogFlow agent! <say-as >${params.original}</say-as>.</speak>`);
  conv.data.question = 'question1';
});
```